# How to dynamically enable/disable swiping to either side for a CN1 SwipeContainer?

Tags: codenameone

I have a case where I need to dynamically enable/disable the swipe left or swipe right of an already created and displayed `SwipeContainer`. There are no methods for this, only to disable swiping altogether, but I need to do it for each direction separately.

Any suggestions for how to do it anyway or maybe ideas for how it could be done?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this but I suggest using `setHidden(true)` on the component in the side you don't want to show as a workaround.